# Typo in Nash's paper?

Tags: probability, nash-equilibrium

[Nash : Bargaining Problem](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/spring02/papers/nash50a.pdf)

On page 156, Assumption 4, is there is typo?

Shouldn't it read, *"If A, B and C are as in assumption 2, ..... which is just as desirable as **B**..." ?* (There is no non-trivial  way for their combination to be equal to **C)**.

Comment: At first glance, anyhow, yes, it seems like it ought to be $B$. He discusses $B$ as being between $A$ and $C$ and calls it a continuity condition. That sounds like between-ness to me.  I don't have familiarity enough with the subject matter to assert this is definitely true though.

Comment: Yes it is a typo